# how to execute bash for 3 minutes then shut down the machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, at-job

I want to run bash in a specific time(With at command ) for 3 minutes after that, I want to shut down the machine

> This is my bash code (send.sh) :

```
$ x=10
echo The value of variable x = $x
```

> and this is my `at` command :

```
at 2:30 PM tomorrow
```

what should I write in `send.sh` for running for 3 minutes and then shutting down the machine

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: `sleep 180; shutdown`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you want to execute the "waiting" part inside of your script: you can simply do the following, using `at` (pseudo-code):

```
at 2:30 PM tomorrow, launch "send.sh"
at 2:33 PM tomorrow, shut down your machine
```

The problem is that, if you put it somewhere in "send.sh", the following might happen:

send.sh content:

```
<do something>
<wait for three minutes>
<shut down your machine>
```

1. The `<do_something>` might take some time, and the shut down will be launched later than the expected three minutes.
2. The `<do_something>` might go wrong, causing your script to abort and your machine won't be shut down at all.

Hence my proposal to create two separate `at` entries.

**Edit, after comment from Socowi:**

Apparently, one can add an `at`-clause after a command, as follows:

```
echo shutdown | at now + 3 minutes
```

This might be the solution you're looking for.

Comment: The second `at` command can be added to the top of the script, so that a shutdown is scheduled automatically each the time script runs: `echo shutdown | at now + 3 minutes`.

Answer (score 1):

The `timeout` command might be what you're looking for.
It will send a `TERM` signal to the running command after a specified amount of time. Additionally, you can specify that it will send an *additional* `KILL` signal in case that the command is reluctant to react to the `TERM` signal.
Here is a sceleton script that you can modify for your purpose:

```
#!/bin/bash

{ sleep 180; echo shutdown; } &

timeout --verbose --kill-after 1 180 \
    bash -c "trap 'echo TERM received, exiting gracefully!; exit' SIGTERM; while true; do sleep 1; echo Sending stuff...; done"
```

The whole purpose of my while loop is to simulate something that might be going on for more than 3 minutes. I've added a signal trap that gets fired once the `TERM` signal has been sent, in order to give the script a chance to exit gracefully when its time has come. Remove the `echo` in front of the `shutdown` once you've tested your script and you're satisfied with the result.

Here's the script in action:

```
~/$ ./send.sh 
Sending stuff...
Sending stuff...
  (truncated)
Sending stuff...
timeout: sending signal TERM to command ‘bash’
shutdown
Terminated
TERM received, exiting gracefully!
```